# How to use TEMPLATE_TEST_CASE with pairs of types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, catch2, std-variant

I am trying to use catch2 [TEMPLATE_TEST_CASE](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/test-cases-and-sections.md#type-parametrised-test-cases) for pairs of types, i.e. instead of templating a single type for each test, I need to use a correlated pair of types. I thought I could use `std::variant` to store these pairs, but compilation fails with: `error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token. auto outtype = std::get<0>(TestType);`.

I'd appreciate any help for the reason of this error or an alternative solution to this problem.
Here is the code snippet:

```cpp
    using varA = std::variant<OutputA, InputA>;
    using varB = std::variant<OutputB, InputB>;

    TEMPLATE_TEST_CASE("test", "[test][template]", varA, varB) {
    auto outtype = std::get<0>(TestType);
    auto intype  = std::get<1>(TestType);
    }
```

Comment: Maybe, you confused [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) with [std::tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)? In a `std::variant`, only one type can be active at most. (Imagine `std::variant` as the modern replacement of `union`.) For what you do in your test case, I believe you want to access OutputX _and_ InputX.

Comment: Btw. regardless whether you use `std::variant` or `std::tuple`, `std::get()` is a function to access a _value_ but you provide a type. Following the example in the doc., `TestType` could be used to make an instance (of the current tested type out of the sequence of types to test), and then you may access that via `std::get()`. Maybe, something like `TestType test; auto outtype = std::get<0>(test); auto intype = std::get<1>(test);` (and the `TestType` still rather a `std::tuple` but not a `std::variant`...)

Comment: FYI: [The doc.](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/test-cases-and-sections.md#type-parametrised-test-cases) I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . instead of templating a single type for each test, I need to use a correlated pair of types.

If is only a pair of types, I suppose you can use `std::pair`; `std::tuple`, for more types.

I suppose you can try something as

```
TEMPLATE_TEST_CASE("test", "[test][template]", std::pair<OutputA, InputA>, std::pair<OutputB, InputB>) {
  typename TestType::first_type outvalue = /* some initial value */;
  typename TestType::second_type invalue = /* some initial value */;
}
```

With `std::tuple`, to access the single types, you can use `std::tuple_element`, so

```
TEMPLATE_TEST_CASE("test", "[test][template]", std::tuple<OutputA, InputA>, std::tuple<OutputB, InputB>) {
  std::tuple_element_t<0u, TestType> outvalue = /* some initial value */;
  std::tuple_element_t<1u, TestType> invalue = /* some initial value */;
}
```

Comment: `std::pair` was what I was looking for. Thank you very much. As a newbie for C++, could you let me know why we need to add `typename`?

Comment: @Armut - In this particular case, isn't needed; I've corrected the answer. But there are cases where you have to say yo the compiler that whats follows is a type. And I never remember when, exactly, is required. More info in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: Thank you for the link @max66, I'll try to understand. Indeed for this case, I cannot compile (gcc 9) without adding `typename`. I get a surprisingly clear error: `error: need ‘typename’ before ‘TestType:: first_type’ because ‘TestType’ is a dependent scope`.

Comment: @Armut - As I've said, I never remember when, exactly, is requested (in a little test with my compiler, I don't need it... but I don't use catch2 for my test... maybe `TEMPLATE_TEST_CASE` introduce something that impose `typename`). Reintroduced `typename` in the answer.